# Error after deploying to hosting

Tags: jakarta-ee, openshift

I'm using Eclipse IDE. I'm using Jboss. My project is java EE. I chose Dynamic web project when creating my project. My project runs well on local. But I didn't use Maven on my project.
I exported my project to ROOT.war file. I created an application Jboss on OpenShift and clone it. Then put ROOT.war file in subfolder /deployments.
Using Git

```
git commit -a -m 'message'
git push
```

ROOT.war deployed. But few .xhtml files runs well (that are static xhtml files). Files use CDI is error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /tailieu/danhmuc.xhtml @13,53 value="#{docuCat.cat}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'docuCat' resolved to null
```

Can you guess what reasons cause the error. I will check?

Comment: What do the log files say?

Comment: OpenShift is currently upgrading. I can't log in my app by Git to view log. I used Jboss tool on eclipse. This tool works fine. But I don't know how to view log with this tool. I'm waiting for OpenShift to back to nomal.

Comment: It's an item available in the right click menu ( I think on the application)